# How do I create a leader line for a label in my bar graph in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, editing, analysis, statistics, labeling

I am displaying a bar graph of various tornado watches and warnings along with the actual tornado touchdowns themselves. Since the tornado touchdowns are such a small number compared to the large quantity of watches/warnings I would like to label the number of tornado touchdowns with their specific number. The problem is that when I display the label (called a mark within the properties window) it covers my points on the graph. **I would like to create some type of "leader line" to move the labels away from my points.** I have enclosed a picture of something kind of like how i want it - I drew the sloppy little black lines is if they were leader lines and somewhere near the end is where I would like to move the labels so they don't cover my points on the graph. **If there are any suggestions I would appreciate it.** Thanks a bunch.

[image]